# Zend Framework 1.8

Tags: zend-framework

In the new version of ZF, we must use:

> require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
>   Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

insted of:

> require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
>   Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();

But the models, aren't working anymore :(.I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Launch' not found in C:\wamp\www....

If I don't remove the line:

> Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();

I'm getting a notice:

> Notice: Zend_Loader::Zend_Loader::registerAutoload is deprecated as of 1.8.0 and will be removed with 2.0.0; use Zend_Loader_Autoloader instead in C:\wamp\www.....

And I have set the include path for the models, my current setup works fine with 1.7

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

For more details, I wrote an article about it. Matthew Weier O'Phinney did too. You should also check out the docs:

- http://akrabat.com/zl18
- http://devzone.zend.com/article/4525-Developing-a-Comprehensive-Autoloader
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html

Answer (score 0):

> $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
>     $autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);

works!